# How to setup observation space with multilevel features in OpenAi Gym for SIMPLE package?

Tags: python, openai-gym

I want to use the [SIMPLE](https://github.com/davidADSP/SIMPLE) package to train a model on a custom board game. The package is based on OpenAi Gym.
The observation space contains these elements:

- position of characters: array of length x with each value being an integer between 0 and 11
- score of characters: array of length x with each value being an integer between 0 and 51
- current player: integer between 0 and i
- current position of special item: integer between 0 and 11
- result of dice: integer between 1 and 6

1. How would I define such an observation space in the code?
2. I think that gym.spaces.Dict() might be an approach but I am not sure whether the SIMPLE package can handle Dict spaces. Is this so?

Comment: You should be able to define your observation space using `gym.spaces.Dict()` types and in the event SIMPLE does not support this observation space, you can simply flatten your observation space

Comment: How would I define the first array, for example. Is it simply gym.spaces.Discrete(x)?

Comment: Yes, a discrete space would be just that. See the source if you want: https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/spaces yours would all be discrete I believe

Comment: Thanks alot! I should be able to take it from here